# Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId

Tags: apex, community, permissions, customer-community

I'm trying to allow users in the community portal of Profile type Customer Community Login to create Contacts and Users. I am getting an issue when they try inserting a user: "Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId" and I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Some of the most common answers I have seen is to change my Apex code to "without sharing" but this isn't an option for me (due to security reasons). I have also seen answers that refer to permissions that are not available on the Customer Community Login profile type. Has anyone dealt with this issue or know what I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case for allowing a community user to create a contact and user? Maybe you can approach the problem in a different way. Alternatively, if it doesn't need to happen immediately, you could schedule a batch job with a user that has permission to create contacts and users and have that code do the creation of the records you want.

Comment: Are you using with sharing in that case current profile may not have access. Use a without sharing handler class to bypass that.